# OpenVPN TOTP prompt

Tags: prompt, openvpn, pam, totp

I configured OpenVPN to use user/password authentication via PAM, which works fine. I tried to add TOTP authentication too (also with PAM), which won't work.

The client version is exactly the same as the server version (it shouldn't be a version mismatch issue). I tried to run server and client as nobody enable/disabled, nothing helped. If I enable the static-challenge option on client side, the prompt is displayed, but the input isn't handled (it isn't passed toward PAM). However the user/password login is working fine, which is also handled by PAM.
The PAM configuration openvpn is correct, as the same works with SSH well.
The PAM prompt is passed to the OpenVPN server, as this appears in the server log: `One-time password (OATH) for 'user1':`  but this never appears on client side.

- Can somebody please help me with this? Is there a missing compile option, or a known bug, or does this need a different configuration?

  ```
  openvpn --version
  OpenVPN 2.5.6 x86_64-suse-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 16 2022
  library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021 SUSE release 150400.7.37.1, LZO 2.10
  Originally developed by James Yonan
  Copyright (C) 2002-2022 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
  Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no 
  enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes 
  enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown 
  enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown 
  enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes 
  enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes 
  enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no 
  enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes 
  enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes 
  enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no 
  enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_small=no 
  enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no 
  enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes 
  enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix 
  with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no 
  with_sysroot=no
  ```
- PAM config:

  ```
  cat /etc/pam.d/openvpn
  #%PAM-1.0
  auth        requisite   pam_oath.so usersfile=/etc/oath/users_ssh.oath window=30 digits=6 
  auth        requisite   pam_nologin.so
  auth        include     common-auth
  account     requisite   pam_nologin.so
  account     include     common-account
  password    include     common-password
  session     required    pam_loginuid.so
  session     include     common-session
  session     optional    pam_lastlog.so   silent noupdate showfailed
  ```
- openvpn server conf (only relevant):

  ```
  username-as-common-name
  #plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so "openvpn"
  plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so "openvpn login USERNAME password PASSWORD pin OTP"
  ```
- Client conf (relevant part):

  ```
  auth-user-pass
  #static-challenge "PIN" 1
  ```

I'm trying to connect with enabled TOTP on the server, and I get `AUTH_FAILED` (instead of success), regardless of typing the PIN to static-challenge prompt.